# scope issue caused ng-click don't trigger

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I uses angular ui tab (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and I added a delete btn inside the the js file. I can't do it with my markup because the js generate the template on the js side.

my ng-click doesn't work when I put this

```
<span ng-click="deleteTab()" >dlt</span>
```

js

```
$scope.deleteTab = function(){
    //$scope.tabs.splice(this, 1);
    alert('d');
}
```

within my controller. I tried to include the js on the topest and before the , nothing work. Until I try onClick. I wonder why I can't use ng-click in my situation?

Comment: two fundamental questions, have you put a controller in the html part where you put the button? If the answer is yes, have you puth the method inside the controller? Can you put more code?

Comment: this method is in the html file or within controller??

Comment: @mautrok look at this plnkr.co/edit/CAlrAzHO2THuglQrsTIi?p=preview I can't add a x button to make the tab delete-able unless I edit the code in angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.5.0.js –  user3398172

Answer (score 0):

If you add new HTML to the DOM without using angular, you need to `$compile` the HTML to let angular to bind the content and `$watch` changes. [See the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler)

```
 $compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

**Edit:-**
Ah you can give the title as a HTML template as well,[see the tabs definition](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

```
 <tab  ng-repeat="workspace in workspaces"

             active=workspace.active>
             <tab-heading>{{workspace.name}}<span ng-click="deleteTab()" >dlt</span></tab-heading>
            <div ng-controller="TabsChildController" >
                <div>
                    {{workspace.id}} : {{ workspace.name}}
                </div>
                <input type="text" ng-model="workspace.name"/>
            </div>     
        </tab>
```

and [here is the solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/mrOMgMS4Yp0xygwnUMOt?p=preview)

Comment: I added ng-click into the angularjsui.js and declare the function in my own js. is there any more simpler solution?

Comment: Why can't you add it in the HTML? what type of UI component are you going to create using Bootstrap ? You need to give some more code here..

Comment: look at this http://plnkr.co/edit/CAlrAzHO2THuglQrsTIi?p=preview

I can't add a x button to make the tab delete-able unless I edit the code in http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.5.0.js

Comment: what do you mean. It can be clicked.. check it now, I have added your alert to it .

Comment: ok let's say I want it to be appeared when the tab is an active tab and when it's hovered. I add ngmouseover to angularui.js and ng-show to my markup it doesn't work.

Comment: That's a separate question, anyway why do you add it to angularui.js ? Now everything is in our HTML page.

Comment: no, look at the <li> generated by the template. I've no control over it if it's still in the template. I posted a problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22801966/scope-confusion-on-generated-dom-by-template

Comment: Didn't Fix your first question ?

Comment: `<tab-heading ng-mouseover="showDelete()">{{workspace.name}}<span ng-click="deleteTab()" >dlt</span></tab-heading>` Still you can do like this.

Comment: yea I tried that but not on the entire <li>, tab-heading is the text length. bad UX.

Answer (score 0):

that's a plunker that could solve your problem.[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nkmCKJnJhKRLVFMn8Lq4?p=preview) the only doubt is what workspace would you want to close, i imagine it is the last, otherwise you only need to modify the delete method.

## EDIT

in this version you can delete the selected workspace, you have to controll the css, but i thin it could be a good solution
[new plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5aDcesHfKrmpWE8iYq5Z?p=preview)

Comment: I want to put it at the end of each of the tab